# what does $t mean in underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following code

```
   data.feed.entry.sort( function ( a, b ) {
      var aName = a.title.$t.toLowerCase(),
          bName = b.title.$t.toLowerCase();
      return ( aName < bName ) ? -1 : 1;
   });
```

What does $t mean in underscore.js?

Comment: **Don't see `_` there**, the code is pure JavaScript. Can you add complete code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with underscore.js, it must come from your data provider (it’s a property on `data.feed.entry[].title`)

Comment: `$t` is just a property name like `title`. Nothing special.

Comment: `console.log(a.title.$t);` could give you a hint

Comment: BTW, that comparator function is broken, it should return zero when `aName === bName`, not one.